# I want to preload the options of a dropdown based on the selected option of another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to preload Local government area inside a dropdown, when a state is selected from an initial dropdown.

How do I achieve this with Javascript or Jquery.

The javascript code not working

```
var val = $("#state").val();
    if (val == "abuja"){
        $("#lga").append('<option value=1>My option</option>');
    }else if (val == "abia"){
        $("#lga").append('<option value=2>Goto</option>');
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your entire code?

Comment: Are you using Ajax?